# How to get all messages from IBM MQ in Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I am new to Queues, I have a queue where the messages are published individually. Using a scheduler I need to consume all the messages in the IBM MQ connector at that particular time.

Since consume only fetches one message at a time and the scheduler will only run once a day. So how can I achieve the requirement of fetching all the messages from the queue?

Can anyone suggest if this is achievable and if yes what would be the approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your question refers to using the IBM MQ Connector in a Mule application deployed in Mule 4, which is a product of a company called MuleSoft.

Queues are not normally used in that way. Messages are read and processed one at a time. If you need to read all messages just use a [listener](https://docs.mulesoft.com/ibm-mq-connector/1.6/ibm-mq-listener) to receive all messages. If you need to read one message at a given time use the [consume](https://docs.mulesoft.com/ibm-mq-connector/1.6/ibm-mq-consume) operation. However if you want to process all possible message at in a certain period of time, you have a couple of alternatives to achieve that:

- Use a listener as the source of a flow and in the body of the flow add a choice to check if the time of the day is appropriate. If not rollback the message into the queue again by using [manual acknoledgement](https://docs.mulesoft.com/ibm-mq-connector/1.6/ibm-mq-ack#manual-acknowledgement) and throwing an error before the flow finishes.
- Use the scheduler to [start and stop the listener flow programmatically](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Stop-Or-Start-Flows-In-Mule-4-x-Programmatically) at appropriate times. This may or may not work because it can confuse the connector and throw errors. I have seen that happened in the past.

My recommendation would be to avoid doing this and just use a listener to read all messages. Ask the sender to only send messages a the appropriate time ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the details. The messages in queue is added in real-time and continuous, so, can't have a restriction on sending messages at a particular time :-(.

Comment: Is there a valid reason to only process a certain time of the day? What happens if not all messages can be processed at that time?

Comment: From the queue, the messages are pushed to the database, and the user wants to run a report for that particular day from the db.